# Why am I getting no main manifest attribute on .less file watcher in webstorm and less compiler?

Tags: less, webstorm

I'm getting this message:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 7.0.1\jre\jre/bin/java" -jar "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/WebStorm 7.0.1/plugins/lessc-plugin/lib/lessc-plugin.jar" page1.less
>   no main manifest attribute, in C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/WebStorm 7.0.1/plugins/lessc-plugin/lib/lessc-plugin.jar

Any one has a clue why is that?

Comment: "_no main manifest attribute_" Sounds like that's your problem.

Comment: I jsut installed the lessc-plugin from jetbrain to webstorm.
What kind of problem it might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact plugin author. This plugin is NOT written by JetBrains.

---

WebStorm has **File Watcher plugin** which helps in compiling LESS/SASS/CSS/JS/TypeScript/etc, but you still need to install LESS compiler yourself.

For more details: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5508473#5508473

Comment: Thanks,
Works like a charm indeed :)